# Conditional automatic variable

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, callstack

```
void function(typeA* ptr_to_A) {
  if (!ptr_to_A) {
    typeB B; // typeB is a derived class of typeA
    ptr_to_A = &B;
  }
  do_stuff_to_ptr_to_A(ptr_to_A);
  // my hope is that B is still in scope here so that this function will operate on my B object (which is on the stack) which only gets created if ptr_to_A was initially NULL
}
```

Will this function do what I think it does (what I want it to do)? That is, only allocate B on the stack if the argument was a null pointer?

Comment: It seems so, unless typeB has some sort of move semantics.

Comment: `B` won't be in scope because it goes out of scope at the end of the if statement when it reaches the closing brace.

Comment: @chris thanks for pointing that out. So my `do_stuff_to_ptr_to_A` function will not be a happy customer, I presume. This is what happens when switching from JS to C++. What's the right way to do this? Manually allocate my `B` on the heap?

Comment: @StevenLu, You might want to look into it more, but pointers in C++ shouldn't be all that common, what with references and RAII-aware classes available. Their best use is for pointing to something that isn't dynamically allocated and which a reference doesn't suit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will this function do what I think it does?

No, it's undefined behavior because `B` goes out of scope. Since this is undefined behavior anything can happen, and therefore you can't predict the results. You want to keep `B` in at least the same scope as the function call, so just move it to the top of the method:

```
void function(typeA* ptr_to_A) {
   typeB B; // typeB is a derived class of typeA
   if (!ptr_to_A) {
      ptr_to_A = &B;
   }
   do_stuff_to_ptr_to_A(ptr_to_A);
}
```

But if you only want to allocate a `typeB` if `ptr_to_A` is null then you could do this:

```
void function(typeA* ptr_to_A) {
  if (!ptr_to_A) {
    typeB B; // typeB is a derived class of typeA
    do_stuff_to_ptr_to_A(&B);
  } else {
    do_stuff_to_ptr_to_A(ptr_to_A);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring B of typeB within braces which means it will only be valid within that conditional if-statement i.e. gone out of scope.  Declare B before the if-statement.
B will only be assigned when ptr_to_A is null.
If you intend to pass ptr_to_A out of the function "function()" you will be in trouble as B is function local.

Comment: So B is local to the function so if execution exits `function` it's sure to be gone. But is it also undefined behavior to access B where I try to access it?

Comment: @StevenLu, Yes, it's gone out of scope and had its destructor called before the call to `do_stuff_to_ptr_to_A`.

Comment: @StevenLu: Yes, it's UB. B isn't local to the function. It's local to the enclosing block.